# Windows SVN Ignore File From Commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working with a NetBeans project and store the nbproject folder inside the project, which is all located inside an svn trunk.

Is there a way to keep a non-versioned copy of a file in a repository?

For example, keep a copy in the repo allowing it to be checked out, but not allow updates to it in the repo?

I need this because the project.properties file NetBeans creates has different contents between different developer's machines...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, using one SVN url all developers will download the same content.  However, the solution to have similar effect with the help of SVN externals might look as following:

Create one path per developer machine in repo:

```
   /project/ 
     ...<project_files>
   /developers/
       /mike
          /project -> external to /project 
          project.properties - Mike's properties
       /john
          /project -> external to /project 
          project.properties - John's properties

       ...
```

In this case every developer will be working with common project and own version of project.properties (and of course, in this case SVN URL will be different for each of them).

Another approach is keeping these project.properties files under different names in the project folder and then using very simple setup shell script rename or set symbol link to the correct one (but that goes out of scope of svn).